# abstract method declared in one class and implemented in a derived partial class

Tags: c#

I am making changes to code in which `myFunc()` declared and called within a parent class, where it is declared abstract. And it is actually implemented in the derived class? I know partial classes have this property where the definition can be split over multiple files - but the classes A and B are in different namespaces and both do not use the keyword "`partial`".

Is this code implemented correctly? Or is it violating a C# language rule?

File1.cs

```
namespace PQR
{
    public abstract class A : UserControl
    {
       protected abstract void myFunc(); //no definition because it is declared abstract
    }

    protected void use_myFunc(int i)
    {
        //call myFunc(). called in a parent class, 
        //where it is declared abstract. And  
        //it is actually implemented in the derived class???
        myfunc();
    }
}
```

File2.cs

```
namespace ABC
{
    public partial class B : PQR.A
    {
       protected override void myFunc() 
       {
          //do something.
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to know if the code will compile I suggest entering the code into visual studio, or calling the compiler directly if you want, and seeing what the results are yourself.  You don't need us to tell you *if* it compiles.

Comment: Correct, yes. Violation, no.

Comment: I won't bother posting an answer because your code looks semantically correct.

Comment: @RitchMelton The code actually won't compile as is...it's pretty close though.

Comment: @Servy: OP is not asking if the code compiles. He's asking if the proper convention is being followed. Which, by the way, it is.

Comment: @code4life A C# language rule would be the rules defining what is valid C# code, not *guidelines* which just define what good suggestions are.  And in any case, it doesn't compile, so the quality of the code is irrelevant if it doesn't actually compile.

Comment: Dont get confused with "partial" classes. You are just inheriting a class

Comment: @Servy: and the OP has written valid C# code, in terms of the structure he has laid out. It just doesn't compile, but that's **syntax**, not structure. Let's not beat him over the head when he's just starting out on the journey. I'm sure you were once in his situation at one point in your life.

Comment: Yes, I was not asking if the code compiles or not. I am aware of Polymorphism and inheritance. What really confuses me with the code base i am looking at is that NOT both the classes are using the "PARTIAL" modifier and it still works and compiles. I am reading from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @code4life What makes you think that he's asking about the conceptual approach and not the syntax.  What he asked for what the later, not the former.  If you want to provide both, that's fine, I wouldn't discourage that, but to claim that I'm "beating him over the head" for answering the question that he asked, instead of just assuming that he knew better and ignoring the problem entirely, is inappropriate in my mind.

Comment: Thanks all. I am only asking from a conceptual standpoint.

Comment: @code4life: Is it mandatory to use the "PARTIAL" modifier?

Comment: @Code12: no, it's not mandatory. But if you have a situation where the class code is going to be split up into multiple files, you are required to use the `partial` modifier.

Comment: @Servy: my last comment on this topic: `You don't need us to tell you if it compiles.` I wouldn't call that much of a help. I went through this sort of crap with Joel's (the fogbugz guy) last website and I don't think it really helps to foster this kind of mentality. It drives noobs completely off the site.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of inheritance and abstract classes is entirely separate from partial classes.

When a class is marked as `partial` it means that it will, when trying to compile that class, look through all of your code files for another class in your project that has the same namespace, the same class name, and is also marked as `partial`.  It will then combine the code from those definitions into one single class definition.  The end result is almost the same as if you had copy/pasted the text from each of the partial classes into one class.

You don't actually need to have multiple instances of a partial class.  If you mark a class a `partial` and provide no additional partial implementations then that's **just fine**.  It won't be a compiler error.  It will just compile that class as the entire definition of that class, just the same way it would if `partial` weren't there.

Inheritance is entirely separate from that concept.  When a class is marked as `abstract` it will be compiled into it's own type, and the definitions of that type will exist (separately from all implementations of it) in the compiled assembly.

When you inherit from a class (whether it was abstract or not) it doesn't "combine" the classes at compile time.  They remain separate types that will exist in the compiled code.  For each type it will have its own table that lists all of the methods of that type and where the definition of it is.  For each of the derived type's new methods it will point to that definition in the new type.  For a method inherited from the base class and not overridden it will reference the base class.  For virtual methods that are defined in the base class but overridden in the derived class it will point to the derived class.  Using this it can always find the actual implementation of each method.  It does this at runtime right when it tries to call the method.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is called inheritance and polymorphism.

This is used when you know that something has to be done, but the implementation of that 'something' varies depending on the type of the instance that is executing.

It is not violating any rule.  In fact, this pattern even has a name: [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question that he asked.

Comment: +1 to offset the -1: I think it answers the question very well.

Comment: @code4life `"Is this code implemented correctly? Or is it violating a c# language rule?"`  This doesn't answer that question.  It gives a name to what it's doing, but doesn't state whether that's a good or bad thing to do.  It also doesn't answer the question of whether or not it will compile (it won't).

Comment: I can't see any part where the TS asks if the code will compile.  Oh, and sorry, I didn't know that certain people are not able to read between the lines. :roll:

Comment: @Servy: there is a lot of code in SO that doesn't compile properly (mine included, LOL). However, the OP is a relatively new programmer, and just wants to know what is the correct way to use polymorphic methods. I don't know why we should insist his code must compile. I'm sure he can figure that out on his own spare time.

Comment: @Servy, he's not asking whether the code compiles, he's asking if the code is conceptually correct.  Any monkey can fix compile errors.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels That could be rather insulting to the OP if he is indeed having problems getting his code to compile.  It's a common problem that very new users have.  I'd rather help him through the process of learning how to debug compiler errors than ignore the problem and insult his intelligence.

Comment: @Servy, OP nowhere asks if the code compiles, or how to fix compile errors ...  (fixing compiler errors is not called debugging).  It is obvious that the posted code is just some code to illustrate the situation that OP wants to discuss.  It is absolutely normal that there are compile-errors in that kind of code, since it is very probably being typed directly here, and not verified by any compiler.  (At least, I do it all the time when posting on SO).

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra '}' after "protected abstract void myFunc();", but other than that it looks fine. The "partial" won't hurt, but it won't play a role either; it gives you the ability to split the declaration of the same type across different files, but it does not play a role on how inheritance is dealt with.

Comment: The method call of `myFunc` doesn't have the correct casing, so that also doesn't compile.  Also `use_myFunc` isn't defined in any class, so that won't compile.

Comment: @Servy I did notice the odd location of the method, but assumed it was a misplaced '}'. Didn't notice the casing error, but I understand the question as more conceptual than 'why does not this compile' really.

Comment: It's easy enough to just copy-paste the code into visual studio.  Why just look and guess when you can let the C# compiler tell you *for certain* if it will compile, and if not, why.